# MobX + React Native not re-rendering

Tags: javascript, react-native, mobx-react

I am building a password reset with react native and MobX I am having a bit of trouble reseting the error state. I have tried multiple solutions but none seem to be working, the onChangeText for the input seems to be working but my boolean value doesn't work for updating the UI, I can see the store logging out and it seems correct but the UI doesn't seem to be adding the error message I am using also using react native navigation:

```
navigation.navigate('Forgot');
```

and heres my class:

```
import React from 'react';
import { action, observable } from 'mobx';

/**
 *
 */
class PasswordResetStore {
  @observable email = '';
  @observable emailError = false;

  @action setEmail = (value) => {
    console.log(this.emailError);
    this.emailError = true;
    this.email.value = value;
  };
}

const passwordResetStore = new PasswordResetStore();
export const PasswordResetContext = React.createContext(passwordResetStore);
```

and heres my component:

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import { Text, Input, Button } from 'react-native-elements';

import { observer } from 'mobx-react';

import { PasswordResetContext } from '../store/PasswordResetStore';

const PasswordReset = observer(() => {
  const store = useContext(PasswordResetContext);

  return (
    <View>
      <View>
        <Text h3>Reset your password</Text>
      </View>

      <View>
        <Text>Enter the email your used to sign up</Text>
        <Input
          onChangeText={store.setEmail}
          value={store.email.value}
          placeholder="Email"
          keyboardType={'email-address'}
          autoFocus={true}
          autoCorrect={false}
          maxLength={256}
          autoCapitalize={'none'}
          errorMessage={store.emailError ? 'email not found' : ''}
        />
        {/*<Button onPress={store.onResetPassword} title="Search" />*/}
      </View>
    </View>
  );
});

export default PasswordReset;
```

Thanks

Initial load (where you see true I should be seeing the validate error)
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HYcAy.png

Updated:
added a reset but still not showing up the boolean values are correct:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      store.reset();
    };
  }, []);
```

```
  @action reset = () => {
    this.emailError = false;
  };
```

Comment: Is it intentional that the button in commented out? I see nothing that should reset the store. Also I don't see [store.]onResetPassword anywhere defined.

Comment: Yes it is intentional for the purpose of this post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were using MobX 6 then you now need to use `makeObservable` method inside constructor to achieve same functionality with decorators as with MobX 5 before:

```
import { makeObservable } from "mobx"

class PasswordResetStore {
  @observable email = '';
  @observable emailError = false;

  constructor() {
    // Just call it here
    makeObservable(this);
  }

  @action setEmail = (value) => {
    console.log(this.emailError);
    this.emailError = true;
    this.email.value = value;
  };
}
```

Although there is new thing that will probably allow you to drop decorators altogether, `makeAutoObservable`:

```
import { makeAutoObservable } from "mobx"

class PasswordResetStore {
  // Don't need decorators now
  email = '';
  emailError = false;

  constructor() {
    // Just call it here
    makeAutoObservable (this);
  }

  setEmail = (value) => {
    console.log(this.emailError);
    this.emailError = true;
    this.email.value = value;
  };
}
```

More info here
https://mobx.js.org/migrating-from-4-or-5.html
and
https://mobx.js.org/react-integration.html

Comment: That works! Funny I swear I was trying that method before, there was probably something else wrong I was doing. Thank you so much!

Comment: The second example works without the @'s! Also it seems I can't reset in the constructor, but using the unmount hook in the `useEffect` and calling it there works.

Comment: I do get a warning tho:
[MobX] Since strict-mode is enabled, changing (observed) observable values without using an action is not allowed. Tried to modify: PasswordResetStore@1.emailError

will look into it maybe because I have the @babel/plugin-proposal-decorators enabled in my babel config.

Comment: In MobX@6 strict mode is enabled by default, you maybe need to configure `enforceActions` flag. Check point 6 from migration guide!

Comment: configure({ enforceActions: 'never' }); in my App,js suppressed the warning. Thanks again!